# Hovering over JButtons and displaying a message

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jbutton, mousemotionevent

I want to hover over a number of JButtons on my GUI (map) and display the name of that location e.g. Manchester and London. I have the code working for one button, but it does not work for more than one button and prints the last `out` message (as i have 10 buttons) for all button locations.

If `button1` is true it then draws the text on the GUI in the specified area via my `paintComponent()` method.

How can i resolve this?

```
button1.addMouseMotionListener(this);
button2.addMouseMotionListener(this);
```

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0)
{
    if(button1.contains(arg0.getPoint()))
    {
        button1  = true;
        out = "test 1";
        repaint();
    }

    if(!button1.contains(arg0.getPoint()))
    {
        b1 = false;
        out = " ";
        repaint();
    }//same for all 10 buttons but change variables
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not use the tool tip API that already exists?

```
button.setTooltip("Manchester");
```

You even use HTML text to produce formatted results.

```
button.setTooltip("<html>Manchester<br>53.4800° N, 2.2400° W</html>");
```

If the images are embedded, you can even supply an image...

```
button.setTooltip("<html><img src=" + getClass().getResource("/someimage") + "/>Manchester<br>53.4800° N, 2.2400° W</html>");
```

Comment: *"If the images are embedded, you can even supply an image..."*  They don't absolutely have to be embedded, though if so that is a) faster & b) usable by sand-boxed apps.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ah true, it could be any valid `URL`

Answer (score 3):

- don't to use `MouseListener` or `MosueMotionListener` from `JButton`, this method are correctly implemented in `JButtons API`,
- there no reason, I can't found reason to use `repaint()` for this job
- another way is add `ChangeListener` to `JButton` and take rellated event(s) from derived `ButtonModel`
- for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about `JFrame` with one `JButton`

Answer (score 3):

Well this answer is coolio for JDK 8 users, so try it out:

for regular text

```
buttonyoumade.setToolTipText("Text you choose");
```

for html use

```
anotherbuttonyoumade.setToolTipText("<html> any valid html code </html>");
```